# Is there a way to get Tag objects instead of Reference ones when listing tags from a repository?

Tags: python, git, github3.py

I'm able to successfully list tags from a repository using `github3` using:

```
repo.iter_refs(subspace='tags')
```

That results in a generator of [github3.git.Reference](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/git.html#github3.git.Reference) objects.  Is there a way for me use a similar mechanism to get [github3.git.Tag](http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/git.html#github3.git.Tag) objects, instead?  Right now I'm forced to convert each `Reference` object into my own version of `Tag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the only way to get a `github3.git.Tag` object back is if you're trying to [retrieve a specific annotated tag](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/repos.html?highlight=tag#github3.repos.repo.Repository.tag) (which is a tag created in a very specific manner).

If this is what you're trying to do then your code would look something like

```
tags = [repo.tag(r.object.sha) for r in repo.iter_refs(subspace='refs')]
```

You can get a lightweight tag (which is what most tags on GitHub actually are) by either your current method or by doing `repo.iter_tags()`. Either will work. The latter will return `github3.repos.RepoTag`, not a `github3.git.Tag` though because the API returns much different information for each.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the `repo.iter_tags()` [call](https://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.Repository.iter_tags) in the docs! Cheers!

Comment: No worries @Piotrek! That's why I keep an eye on this tag. :-D