# list tags and tag content using github3

Tags: python-3.x, github-api, github3.py

We tag commits on a weekly basis, and I want to issue a report to see the tag names and their content, I tried the following using python 3.x and [github3](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py)

```
import github3
g = github3.login(token='qwerty')
r = g.repository(owner='me', repository='mine')
```

so far so good, now I tried looking around for a method that would extract the tags, r has a method called tags, also, looking at the documentation I found RepoTags.
Furthermore I found this question on Stack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051151/is-there-a-way-to-get-tag-objects-instead-of-reference-ones-when-listing-tags-fr?answertab=oldest#tab-top).
Bottom line I'm a new developer and I couldn't get it to work, here are some of my more relevant tries and errors if anyone can point me in the right direction, the end result is to get a list of tags that are available for that repo, and then iter through them to get the content of each tag.

```
t1 = tags(1) 
t1.as_json
```

that returned `<bound method GitHubCore.as_json of <GitHubIterator [1, /repos/owner/repository_name/tags]>>`

I tried `tag = github3.repos.tag.RepoTag` that returned nothing, when I try to see the methods the object 'tag' contains, none of them returned anything useful to me.

Comment: `.as_json()`? You need to *call* the method.

Comment: yeah I did tag = github3.repos.tag.RepoTag(json=r.as_json)

I got this back:

Traceback (most recent call last):                              
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                     
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\github3\models.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.etag = json.pop('ETag', None)                                                      
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pop'                                    
'function' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: No you didn't, you're still not *calling* the as_json method. You're passing a function, which does not have pop.

Comment: ok I just went a different way, the repository object r has a tags method, which I can iterate over, so just list(r.tags()) gave me a list of tags, I didn't post it as an answer since it's not complete yet, I need to get the commits for each tag

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain what your final goal is, but here is how one would iterate over the tags on a repository.

```
import github3


gh = github3.login(token='myAwesomeToken')
repository = gh.repository(owner='owner',
                           repository='myAwesomeProjectWithLotsofTags')
for tag in repository.tags():
    assert isinstance(tag, github3.repos.tag.RepoTag)
    print('{} @ {}'.format(tag.name, tag.commit))
```

For future context, most (if not all) of the methods in github3.py that return lists actually return an iterator that generates the objects you're expecting. You actually have to iterate over them (as is explained in the documentation) to retrieve the items. This allows users to conserve API requests instead of trying to list everything or requiring the user to handle paging.

Comment: it does help, I figured it out like I stated in the comments, though your solution is much more elegant.. I'm still learning :)
Any chance you'd fast forward me one extra step? for each tag, I would like to extract the content of it, what was committed according to our convention, right now I'm sort of doing that, but I get back the sha hash I think, that's not user readable (as I'm trying to create a report of the tags and their content), can you suggest an elegant way to doing that?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean by "content". Do you mean the commits since the last?

Comment: yea, so I do
git log RT_12_17wk27_1.. --oneline to get the commits, then create a new tag:
git tag -a RT_12_17wk27_2 (followed by git push)
and my overall goal is to get a report of each tag and the commits per tag.
I already did something similar with your code based on milestones, now I need to replicate it using tags (in general I have jenkins running a job with my python code) but I found it more challenging.
I appreciate your help and don't wanna take too much of your time, either way thank you very much.

Comment: in case I wasn't clear (cuz I just used your code example) the tag.commit returns the sha commit, how can I 'decode' it and present it as something that a user can actually read?

Comment: So repositories have a few commit-related methods. If you care only about that commit `repository.commit(sha)` will get you all that information. If you want to get all commits between two SHAs `repository.commits(since=earlier_sha, until=later_sha)`.

Comment: I've circled back to this one, let me know if you need a new question. I'm iterating over `for tag in repository.iter_tags()` to get the `x = tag.commit['sha']` then I wanna get the message of each commit I do `t = github3.git.Tag(x)` then `print(t.message)` but I get `'RepoTag' object has no attribute 'pop'`. can someone help? I've tried to play with it a bit but I seem to not understand something here..

Comment: The github3.py API is not designed for you to create the object classes yourself besides the GitHub class.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, I did manage that already, however the SHA itself is not very informative, as in, I'm creating a report with the commits per tag, if the report displays sha's that's not helpful, I need it to display the commit message, is that possible?